# Why am I gettting errors about unpackaged files while trying to build an rpm?

Tags: linux, rpm

Trying to package up wget-1.13.tar.gz into a rpm (I am re-learning this process) and I'm running into these errors when I do a dry run.

```
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
/etc/wgetrc
/usr/bin/wget
/usr/share/info/dir
/usr/share/info/wget.info.gz
/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
RPM build errors:
Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
/etc/wgetrc
/usr/bin/wget
/usr/share/info/dir
/usr/share/info/wget.info.gz
/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
```

There are more paths it complains about so this just a snippet but you should get the idea.

My Spec file is as follows:

```
Name:       wget
Version:    1.13    
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    wget to get wget things

Group:      System Environment/Base
License:    GPL
#URL:       
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot:  /tmp/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root 

#BuildRequires: 
#Requires:  

%description
Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS ... GNU   Wget        has many features to make retrieving large files

%prep
%setup -q


%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}


%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc



%changelog
```

So a basic spec file, where am I going wrong?

Also, the file structure my RPMS is $HOME/rpms/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Now you need to populate `%files` so that the installed files are included in the resultant binary package.

Comment: The easiste way to create a RPM for a new version of something (wget is certainly available as RPM) is to grab the source RPM, unpack that and hack on the specfile. The SRPM usually contains patches to the pristine source, which you should consider for application to your package.